# Ongoing Notification not canceling

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-jobscheduler

We're using a jobScheduler to run a periodic weather network call whose results are posted to an ongoing weather notification.

Here's how we create the notification inside the jobService:

```
private fun createNotification(selectedLocation: City) {
        val resultIntent = Intent(context, SplashActivity::class.java)
            resultIntent.putExtra(AppConstants.IS_ONGOING, true)
            resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

            val resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, 0)
            val notificationView = getComplexNotificationView(selectedLocation) ?: return

            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.packageName)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setSmallIcon(getSmallIconResource(context,
                            if (settings.isFahrenheitEnabled())
                                selectedLocation.currentObservation!!.tempF!!
                            else
                                selectedLocation.currentObservation!!.tempC!!))
                    .setVibrate(null)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setCustomContentView(notificationView)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setGroup(AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_GROUP_ONGOING)
                    .build()

            NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(ONGOING_NOTIFY_ID, notification)
    }
```

In our app's settings, the user can disable the ongoing notification.  Here's how we're trying to cancel it:

```
val jobScheduler: JobScheduler? = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
jobScheduler?.cancel(OngoingNotificationJobService.ONGOING_JOB_ID)

NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel(OngoingNotificationJobService.ONGOING_JOB_ID)
```

The problem:

The cancel call is not clearing the notification.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be using `ONGOING_NOTIFY_ID` with the `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel()` method

Comment: yeah.  I didn't realize I did that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to "NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).cancel()" your previous ONGOING_NOTIFY_ID and not your ONGOING_JOB_ID ;)

Comment: ACK!  You know... you look at it for so long, you stop being able to see the forest for the trees.  Let me change it and just make sure there's no other issues before I give you the check.  Thanks for this!

Comment: too soon to give you the check.  I'll circle back to this in about 10 min :)